# Error 1064 in Insert Statement, You have an error in your SQL syntax near

Tags: mysql, sql

Doing a flask experiment can't solve this MySQL problem, keep getting this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,3)' at line 1")
```

This is my code for the query and also the submission to the database:

```
username = form.username.data
email = form.email.data
password = form.password.data
#TODO ENCRYPT PASSWORDS
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
query = "insert into Users
    values ('" + username+"',"''+email+"','"+password+"')"
cursor.execute(query)
mysql.connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I have tried all the solutions that were suggested in other questions but none of them have worked.

Comment: You have two single quotes before +email.  There should only be one.  P.S. You should be using  prepared statements and parameterized queries otherwise you leave yourself open to SQL Injection attacks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: If you used parameters, you would not have this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here: `values ('" + username+"',"''+email+"','"+password+"')"`
It should be: `values ('" + username+"','"+email+"','"+password+"')"`